# Upgrade to hibernate 4: org.hibernate.TransactionException: unable to commit against JDBC connection

Tags: hibernate, quartz-scheduler, jta

I'm trying to upgrade a project from Hibernate 3.5 to Hibernate 4.2, but now I get the following exception during spring context initialization (we are using Spring 3.2.2).

Below you can find our configuration.

Any idea on what can be the cause of the exception?
Reverting the hibernate version to 3.5 the exception disappear.

```
...
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'CLUSTERED_Scheduler' defined in class path resource [etc/scheduling/quartz-scheduling-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateSystemException: commit failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransactionException: commit failed
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1488)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    ...
Caused by: org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateSystemException: commit failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransactionException: commit failed
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:690)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:105)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:517)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:755)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:724)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerAccessor.registerJobsAndTriggers(SchedulerAccessor.java:328)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(SchedulerFactoryBean.java:511)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1547)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1485)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.TransactionException: commit failed
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:185)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:75)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:513)
    ... 42 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.TransactionException: unable to commit against JDBC connection
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:116)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:178)
    ... 44 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Connection is closed.
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper.checkOpen(PoolingDataSource.java:185)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper.commit(PoolingDataSource.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:112)
    ... 45 more
```

The exception occurs during the initialization of a Quartz scheduler bean. This is our configuration:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean"
    name="CLUSTERED_Scheduler" lazy-init="true">

    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
    <property name="overwriteExistingJobs" value="false" />
    ...
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
    p:dataSource-ref="dataSource" 
    p:persistenceXmlLocation="classpath:persistence.xml">
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"
            p:database="${jpa.database}" 
            p:showSql="${jpa.showSql}"
            p:generateDdl="${jpa.generateDdl}"
            p:databasePlatform="${jpa.databasePlatform}" />
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" name="npp"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
    p:entityManagerFactory-ref="entityManagerFactory"
    p:dataSource-ref="nppDataSource"
/>
```

This is the persistence.xml content:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd"
    version="1.0">
    <persistence-unit name="punit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <class>...</class>
        ...
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.ejb.interceptor"
                value="my.Interceptor" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bug in Spring: [SPR-10395](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-10395) - you should update it to version 3.2.3+